# Equal Space Margin CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a problem regarding margin in float boxes.

Here is the Html and CSS code.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85n4pazb/1/)**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#main {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.box {
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  width: 19%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 1% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

In this code, I actually want these 5 boxes to have equal spacing and the last and first box should touch the edge of the container. The problem is, I'm not able to achieve this task. When I try to put equal margin value, the spacing become equal but the last box does not touch the container. When I increase the margin value then box goes on next line.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix your issue with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Assign `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to your `#main` div, then remove the margin you set for your `.box` div's.

**CSS**

```
#main{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box{
  margin:0 1% 0 0;  /* <-- Remove This */
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85n4pazb/2/)**

```css
*
{
margin:0;
height:0;
}

#main{
width:50%;
background:red;
height:200px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.box{
background:orange;
float:left;
width:19%;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this (left margin is specified first on all boxes and then removed on the first one):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#main {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.box{
background:orange;
float:left;
width:18%;
height:100px;
margin:0 0 0 2.5%;
}

#main > div:first-child{
margin-left:0; 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The widths are calculated so that `5*18% + 4*2.5% = 100%` (5 boxes and thus 4 dividers).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like a solution that requires `Flexbox` or something like `:first-child` (eg. if you need to support older browsers), you could try something like this :

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    height:0;
}

#main {
    width:50%;
    background:red;
    height:200px;
}

#box-wrapper {
    margin:0 -1.1% 0 0;
}

.box {
    background:orange;
    float:left;
    width:19%;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 1% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5f3byan9/).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can make use of the `:last-of-type` selector for adjusting the last `.box` & also you need to float that last one to the right, changing the margin values of the rest to `margin:0 1.25% 0 0;`(so it does not flow to the next row)

[Fiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/85n4pazb/5/)

```
.box{
  background:orange;
  float:left;
  width:19%;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 1.25% 0 0; //changed
}

.box:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 0%;
  float:right;
}
```

But I highly recommend you use flexbox for  these kinda layouts. Makes life much easier.